# Maths behind Pie Menu

Tags: math, user-interface, trigonometry

Can someone explain to me what is the math behind this pie menu? I don't understand how it's rendered at all. Helps are appreciated

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of graphics libraries have function like [Pie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for drawing of [circular sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector). To draw ring sector, like your bottom picture, one could draw all needed circular sectors with large radius, then circle or circular sector with lesser radius to fill center region.